# Is there a way of simplifying $ \sum_{k=2}^{n} ke^{-a(k-2)^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

Quick question, is there a way of further simplifying this sum
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{n} ke^{-a(k-2)^2}
$$
where $a>0$?

Comment: I don't think you can find a simple form for this sum.

Comment: Simple answer No. But ... If you differentiate the Jacobi Theta function you will be getting close & there will certainly be interesting progress you can make ... have look here ...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function

Comment: Where does the question come from? Also try $\sum_{n=1}^b a^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n -\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+b}$

Answer (score 1):

Let’s use the following to get 2 infinite series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^b a^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n -\sum_{n=b}^\infty a_n$$

Therefore:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n} ke^{-a(k-2)^2} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} ke^{-a(k-2)^2} -\sum_{k=n}^\infty ke^{-a(k-2)^2}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} ke^{-ak^2} -\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+n)e^{-a(k+n-2)^2}$$

Now can you find a solution in terms of theta functions? Try differentiating [The third Jacobi Theta function](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta3/02/0001/) to find a closed form. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Of course $\sum_{n=1}^b a^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n -\sum_{n=b}^\infty a_n$ sometimes may be converting something meaningful into a difference of two divergent series.

Comment: @GEdgar For $a>0$, don’t both of the final sums converge?

Comment: @GEdgar There is this book: [Summability Calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.5739) which justifies these types of manipulations even if the two resulting series diverge. In fact, such a manipulation can generalize the discrete sum into a continuous function which is unique when a few conditions are applied.